# XML transformation using XSLT to generate the Text file with repeated rows

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I am working on a small example where I want to transforman XML input file using XSLT to generate a text file.

Here is my input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<result>
    <users>
        <user>
            <user-name>user 1</user-name>
            <blood-group>A-</blood-group>
            <id>4</id>
            <col1>c1</col1>
            <col2>c2</col2>
            <col4>c4</col4>
        </user>
        <user>
            <user-name>user 2</user-name>
            <blood-group>B+</blood-group>
            <id>3</id>
            <col3>c3</col3>
            <col4>c4</col4>
        </user>
    </users>
</result>
```

I want to get an output like this after transforming it with XSLT:

```
User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
user 1    | A-          | 4  | c1   | null | null | null
user 1    | A-          | 4  | null | c2   | null | null 
user 1    | A-          | 4  | null | null | null | c4
user 2    | B+          | 3  | null | null | c3   | null
user 2    | B+          | 3  | null | null | null | c4
```

The idea is each record will be repeated by the number of `col` elements the record is having and each line of the output text will have a value for the particular single `col` element and all other remaining values of `col` will be `null`.

I have created an XSL file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:text>User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="users/user">
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(user-name, '          | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(blood-group, '            | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(id, '   | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(col1, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(col2, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(col3, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="col4" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XSL I got the output as:

```
User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
user 1    | A-          | 4  | c1   | c2   |      | c4
user 2    | B+          | 3  |      |      | c3   | c4
```

I am not clear on what functions can be used to get the desired output. Can someone please help me?

The java code that helps me to do the transformation is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path="/";
        String xml = path+"input.xml";
        String xslt = path+"input.xsl";
        String output = path+"output.txt";
        try {
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
            tr.transform(new StreamSource(xml), new StreamResult(
                    new FileOutputStream(output)));

            System.out.println("Output to " + output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Using the XSL file provided in michael's answer gives me output as:

```
User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
user 1    | A-          | 4  | c1   |      |      | 
user 2    | B+          | 3  |      |      |      | c4
user 2    | B+          | 3  |      |      | c3   | 
user 2    | B+          | 3  |      |      |      | c4
```

Comment: Does you input really have numbered `<col#>` elements?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested for-each over col elements:

```
<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:text>User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="users/user">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'col')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../user-name, '          | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../blood-group, '            | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../id, '   | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col1, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col2, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col3, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="self::col4" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Only there will be empty results instead of null's. If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can make use of custom function.

Comment: Thanks lagivan, it is working perfectly. Can you please provide link to the functions that you are using in the xsl, as I am new to XSL I am not able to understand how it is working.

Comment: What functions do you mean? local-name, position and last? Those are standard XPath functions, you can find them here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Improved the code in the answer a bit be removing $user variable.

Comment: yes, I just started learning on XSLT transformation so don't have knowledge on those functions. Thanks a lot for the xpath link. I can see the function details in the link with clear explanation except for `self::`, can you please tell me the use of `self::` or provide a link where this code is part of like xsl or xpath etc. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools as an authoritative resource.  One important reason for that is that w3schools don't make it at all clear which parts of their information relate to which version(s) of XSLT/XPath - in fact the page you've linked to is all about XPath _2.0_ functions, and this question is about v1.0

Comment: @Chaitanya the canonical resource for XSLT and XPath 1.0 is the specifications themselves, at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath respectively.  The `self::` construct is called an _axis_ and is described in [section 2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0 *(requires support for EXSLT str:align() function)***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:text>User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="users/user/*[starts-with(name(), 'col')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../user-name, '          | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../blood-group, '            | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(../id, '   | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col1, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col2, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="str:align(self::col3, '     | ', 'left')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="self::col4" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @michael, yes, the output results is not matching with the given input xml data.

Comment: Nice, I was working on an answer using the same approach :-)  This will produce the required output but with blank space instead of the word "null", you could fix this with something like `str:align(substring(concat('null', self::col1), 5*boolean(self::col1)), '     | ', 'left')`

Comment: @michael, for some reason the output i am getting is different from the output that is coming in your xsltranform link, I have updated my question for your reference.

Comment: @Chaitanya Are you sure?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes I am getting different output compared to what is shown in xstransform link. When I used the xsl provided by lagivan then I got correct result. But personally I feel your xsl is more easy to read and understand.

Comment: @michael, I'm testing locally using Saxon-B 9.1 and I'm getting the same wrong results as Chaitanya.

Comment: @lagivan bizarre - I've tested locally with `xsltproc` and I get the correct result.

Comment: @lagivan As stated explicitly at the top (in bold!), this is an XSLT 1.0 solution requiring a processor that supports the EXSLT str:align() function. That would be primarily Xalan and libxslt, not Saxon 6.5 - and certainly not Saxon 9. There is no way you could have gotten **ANY** result using str:align() with Saxon, other than an error. Since your own answer uses this function, something doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, this is not true. Saxon-B is an exception. Its development was stopped, its last version is 9.1.0.8. But it supports both XSLT 2.0 and EXSLT.

Comment: @lagivan Okay, that's possible, but if it doesn't return the same result as shown in the demo I have linked to, then the implementation must be buggy.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree as I don't see why your solution should not work. Surprisingly, Chaitanya uses XSLT 1.0 implementation with the same bug then.

Comment: @lagivan That's actually less surprising, given it's Xalan. I have warned against that in OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25841247/3016153

Answer (score 1):

*This is a partial answer showing how to get `null` instead of an empty string for the missing columns*

You have two separate answers now that show how to build a table with the shape you require, the final part of the puzzle is how to put the word "null" in the currently blank columns.  For this you can use a trick like this: instead of simply using `self::colN` in the `value-of`, use

```
substring(concat('null', self::colN), 5*boolean(self::colN))
```

This works because `boolean(self::colN)` is true if the current node is a `colN` and false otherwise, and when treated as a number true is 1 and false is 0.  Therefore, in the true case this becomes something like

```
substring('nullc1', 5) => 'c1'
```

and in the false case it becomes

```
substring('null', 0) => 'null'
```

Comment: Thanks lan, for providing details on how I can show null in output and clear explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In view of the bugs, perhaps you should consider abandoning the EXSLT function in favor of a more 'pedestrian", but purely XSLT 1.0 approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                    '" />

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:text>User Name | Blood Group | Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="users/user/*[starts-with(name(), 'col')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(../user-name, $spaces), 1, 10), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(../blood-group, $spaces), 1, 12), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(../id, $spaces), 1, 3), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(self::col1, $spaces), 1, 5), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(self::col2, $spaces), 1, 5), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat(self::col3, $spaces), 1, 5), '| ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="self::col4" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks michael, but for some reason my program is still giving wrong output which I have mentioned in update part of my question. I am not sure what kind of or version of parser my Java program is using internally. But just for your info, in my Java code the TransformerFactory is of type `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` and the Transformer is of type `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl`

Comment: @Chaitanya I suggest you upgrade (or change) your processor.